# Why buy a paper J-J dictionary instead of using free on-line dictionaries?

Tags: discussion, resources

Apart from lookup by radical in case I don't already know how to type the word, is there any advantage to buying the printed 大辞泉 over using weblio.jp and kotobank.jp?

- Are there more definitions?
- More example sentences?
- More coverage of 方言?
- More thesaurus features?
- More grammar notes?

Weblio and kotobank claim to incorporate 大辞泉 and 大辞林, but I only see 大辞林 results when searching for definitions, and the entries seem concise.  Do I miss out on features if I just search from the main page?

Comment: Don't forget you can buy a paper (or electronic) dictionary that *isn't* freely available online.  It never hurts to have more dictionaries to consult.  I like 明鏡国語辞典!

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Goo](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp), which is my main choice. I've used an electronic version of 大辞林, and goo seems to cover more expression words. It seems to pull [from 大辞泉 as well](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/94579/m0u/%E7%84%B6%E3%82%8B%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D/).

It also has a somewhat extensive [synonym thesaurus](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/15835/m0u/%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A1/), with 使い分け.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where to get 大辞泉 definitions.  For now, this just supports my hypothesis that there's no reason to spend $100 on a paper dictionary unless you're a library and thus are expected to buy such books.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. For the expressions goo doesn't have, I google them, and weblio's 日本語表現辞典 pops up surprisingly often.  Less frequently, zokugo (they explain etymology which is like bleh TLDR sometimes). The wiki also has more info. http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/761#761